# Leaflet marker cluster from JSONP WFS + Popups

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, clustering, popup, json

I'm fairly new to Leaflet and just managed to use Leaflet marker-cluster with a JSONP WFS which provides my data from Geoserver. Now I would like to have a popup for my markers by mouse click. But I do not know where to insert the .bindpopup onEachFeature.
Maybe I have to rewrite my code, but nothing what I've tried works.

At the end I will have more than 100,000 markers. Any ideas for a good performance?

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
var geoJsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();

var geoJsonUrl ='localhost:8080/geoserver/test/ows'; 
var defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'test:bh',
    maxFeatures: 120000,
    outputFormat: 'text/javascript'
    };

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));

$.ajax({
    url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse',
    success: function (data) {          
        console.log(data);
        geoJsonLayer.addData(data);         
        markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);     
        map.addLayer(markers);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the geojson within the success callback

```
success: function(data) {
    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            feature.bindPopup('Hi!');
        } 
    });
    // the rest as before...
    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);     
    map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. But unfortunately my entire layer disappears when I add these lines.

Comment: any error in the console?